# How to get the number after the point on double

Tags: java, math

Ex i input 10.98 and i want to display .98 but the answer on my code is 0.98. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
Double numOne,numTwo;

System.out.print("Enter a decimal num: ");
numOne= Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());


numTwo = numOne - Math.floor(numOne) ;

System.out.printf("%.2f", numTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(result).substring( 1, String.valueOf(result).length() - 1) );
```

instead of last line